# Div not loading with new PartialView from ajax call

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm currently working on new functionality for a project I'm working on where a user can add one or more entries at once.  The steps are the following:

1. Click Add Annual Report(s) button.
2. A Telerik Modal Window pops up with a Drop Down List of statuses.
3. Select the status of Actual and a Date Picker appears (Telerik also).
4. If you instead selected Projected, a Date Picker appears for the Start Date, along with another dropdown for the End Year selection (Projected can run multiple years).
5. Once the date field is filled for either selection, click the Add button.
6. Clicking Add fires an ajax method that hits the server, which creates a list of new Annual Reports and sends that to a Session object.  It then returns back if everything was successful.
7. If successful, display text saying it was a success, then close the window, and update the div containing the list of Annual Reports with the new ones.

This all works so far, however, there is an issue.  As is, when you run this multiple times, the div containing all the Annual Reports bugs out, by which I mean never refreshes after the first time, or uses the previous data.  It will not refresh.  I have turned caching off on my ajax calls, removed alerts, removed setTimeout instances, removed the div and added it back, etc.  None of that seems to refresh the div.

However, if I turn on IE Developer Tools, it works.  I read that IE is notorious for using caching, which is fine sometimes, but in this instance it is not.

Is there any way to turn off the caching and force the div to reload?

Below is my code for what happens.

AddARPartialView.cshtml:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnAdd").click(function (e) {
        //Stop system from proceeding to server immediately
        e.preventDefault();

        //Used for checking Completion
        var success = false;

        //Show spinner while system processes page
        //ShowProgress();

        //Check to see if there was any validation errors
        ShowValidationErrors();

        //There was an error, so do nothing
        if (hasError) {
            //hideprogessbar();
            return false;
        }

        //Save Message
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: "false",
            url: "/PM/AddARPartialView",
            dataType: "json",
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    //Mark Success as true
                    success = true;

                    //Hide the Progress bar and show the success message
                    //hideprogessbar();
                }
                else {
                    //Mark Success as false
                    success = false;

                    //hideprogessbar();
                    var DetailError = 'Error while creating new Annual Reports.  Please contact administrator with below details.'
                        + '\n' + '\n' + result.Error;
                    $("#lblError").show();
                    $("#lblError").text(DetailError);
                }
            },
            error: function (xhtr, e, e2) {
                alert(e + '\n' + xhtr.responseText, 'error', '');
            },
            complete: function () {
                if (success)
                {
                    CloseARModal();
                    UpdateAnnualReports();
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Regular page:

```
function CloseARModal() {
    var arWindow = $("#AnnualReport").data("tWindow");
    arWindow.close();
}

function UpdateAnnualReports() {
    //Show spinner while system processes page
    //ShowProgress();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        cache: "false",
        url: "/PM/ARPartialView",
        success: function (result) {
            $("#divARe").html(result);
        },
        error: function (xhtr, e, e2) {
            if (xhtr.status === 401)
                alert("Session Timeout or Unauthorized to access this webpage");
            else
                alert(e + '\n' + xhtr.responseText);
        }
    });

    //hideprogessbar();
    //alert("New Annual Report(s) added successfully!");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my face sure is red with embarrassment.  I figured out the issue.  If you examine the Ajax calls, you'll note for cache, I have it set to "false".  It should not have quotes around it and instead just be flat out false.

I noted this in someone else's Ajax call and tried it on mine.  Sure enough, the caching issue went away instantly, lol...

So infuriating that a few days of research, trial and error attempts, and just banging my head on the desk wasted due that I had a bad example to follow from the previous contractor.  I should always remember, if it looks odd, question it, lol.